# Noun/verb to describe strong belief in a company as evidenced by joining it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there good noun verb to describe strong belief in a company as evidenced by joining it?

For example,

> we know that company X is amazing because of the endorsement 
>   it has received from investment by prestigious investors and 
>   by the XYZ of (famous executive).

What fits in XYZ that would convey that the executive joined the company because of his strong belief in it? "Poaching" would be a close inverse (company has a strong belief in a hire) although I am don't think that word parallels "investment" in the previous clause.

Comment: XYZ= [One Dollar CEO Salaries](https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/onedollarceosalaries.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I think  [commitment](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/commitment)  may fit in the context described:

> - The state of being emotionally or intellectually devoted, as to a belief or a course of action. (AHD)
>
>   - A profound commitment to the company.

Comment: commitment is close but doesn't entirely convey the sentiment. The first problem is it doesn't suggest in any way that the executive has joined the company. The investors also made a commitment. Was the executive already working there and publicly state that he would not leave? That said "commitment" might be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Foot voting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_voting), or "voting with your feet", usually expresses the opposite sentiment, but technically does apply.

Answer (score 0):

[stamp of approval](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seal-or-stamp-of-approval?q=stamp%20of%20approval)

> An official statement or **indication** that something is accepted or regarded favourably:

- We can't write off Yahoo yet, bacause of Marissa Myer's *stamp of approval*

Not as unambiguous as desired, but works.

Answer (score 0):

How about "**confidence**"?

> The confidence that prestigious executive A has in the future of
>   Company Awesome is clear given his recent announcement to join Awesome
>   as its newest Awesome executive.

Answer (score 0):

> **Participation**
>   Be involved; take part:  (Oxford)

Or

> **[Involvement](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/involvement)** is the act of participating in something.
>   vocabulary.com